# Fix a continuous function $f:X\times X^k\to Y$ multilinear in $X^k$, for $X,Y$ Banach. Is $f:X\to\mathscr{L}(X,\ldots,X;Y)$ continuous?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Fix two infinite-dimensional Banach spaces $X,Y$. We define the space 
$$
\mathscr{L}(X,\ldots,X;Y)=\mathscr{L}(\underbrace{X,\ldots,X}_{k};Y)
$$
to be the set of continuous multilinear operators $T:X^k\to Y$, which is a Banach space under the norm $$\lVert T\rVert_{\mathscr{L}(X,\ldots,X;Y)}=\sup_{\substack{\lVert x_i\rVert_X\le 1 \\ 1\le i\le k}}T(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$$

Now, fix some open set $U\subset X$. It is direct to show that any continuous map $F:U\to\mathscr{L}(X,\ldots,X;Y)$ induces a unique continuous map $F:U\times X^k\to Y$. But is the converse true? More explicitly,

> Let $F:U\times X^k\to Y$ be a continuous map bilinear in $X^k$, so that $F:U\to\mathscr{L}(X,\ldots,X;Y)$ is a well-defined set-theoretic map. Then is $F:U\times\mathscr{L}(X,\ldots,X;Y)$ continuous in the norm topology on $\mathscr{L}(X,\ldots,X;Y)$?

My suspicion is that if this is true, it follows from similar arguments as those that allow us to infer continuous differentiability from differentiability, but I can't quite see if I can get it to work.

As a weaker question, does the quoted statement hold if $F$ is the $k$'th order Gâteaux derivative of some $f:U\to Y$?

Comment: May I suggest you to read "Differential calculus" by Cartan?

Comment: I’m guessing he covers smooth functions on infinite dimensional spaces?

Comment: Nono, it is meant to be very introductive, but the approach is very general.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true even for $k=1$. For instance, let $T(t)$ be a strongly continuous semigroup. Then the map $(t,x)\mapsto T(t)x$ is continuous. It does not follow that the map $t\mapsto T(t)$ is continuous in the operator norm.

Comment: This is similar to a counterexample I was thinking of. The catch is that $t$ and $x$ lie in different spaces. If we let $0\ne\ell\in X^*$, then we can always define $T(x,y)=T(\ell(x))y$. However, why should this be a continuous map $T:X\times X\to X$, just using strong continuity of $T$?

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshine: We have $T(t)x-T(s)y=(T(t)-T(s))y+T(t)(x-y)$. By strong continuity, the first term tends to zero as $t\to s$, and the second is bounded by a constant times $\|x-y\|$.